How to get the size of a pyproj projection
I am using the peirce_q projection in pyproj with
p= Proj('+proj=peirce_q +lon_0=25 +shape=square')
supplying it with global coastlines and want to plot the results using PIL ImageDraw.
How do I set the scale for the results to fit within the pixel coordinates of my image?
